# "This method is obsolete" warning when trying to use App.config file

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

Here's my method:

```
public IList<Member> FindAllMembers()
{
    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        string htmlSource = webClient.DownloadString(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MemberUrl"]);
    }

    XDocument response = XDocument.Parse(htmlSource);
}
```

It's recommending I use the new ConfigurationManager.AppSettings, but I can't find it anywhere in intellisense. I'm sure I'm importing the correct namespaces. Do I need to reference something as well?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using SharpDIC.Api.Interfaces;
using SharpDIC.Api.Models;
using System.Configuration;

namespace SharpDIC.Api.Concrete
{
    class XmlMemberFinder : IMemberFinder
    {
        public IList<Member> FindAllMembers()
        {
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                string htmlSource = webClient.DownloadString(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MemberUrl"]);
            }

            XDocument response = XDocument.Parse(htmlSource);
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is in the `System.Configuration` namespace.  Try adding a reference to the `System.Configuration` assembly.

`System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings` is in the `System` assembly, which is why you can use it without adding a reference.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Try `ConfigurationManager` instead of `ConfigurationSettings`

Answer (score 0):

It is in [`System.Configuration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx).

So you should be able to see it.

Are you missing the assembly reference?

Comment: That's odd. In the code above I am importing the namespace correctly, but I still can't invoke the ConfigurationManager class. I'll see if I have to reference a .NET library first.

Answer (score 0):

Add System.Configuration.dll to your references

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to the `System.Configuartion.dll` library in your project. Then you can use it:

```
string htmlSource = webClient.DownloadString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MemberUrl"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on references-->select Assemblies on left side--> Check
System.Configuration.dll and System.Configuration.install.dll--> Click ok.

Hope this resolves the issue as mine !